# unsigned/signed versioned transaction - format I don't know

Tags: transactions, versionedtransactions

So there is transaction:

```
(signed)
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

(unsigned)
AQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAQADBgSBFG/vZ7BH0uLqDP7F3xctpG+EORzAS1lhFalHTq56fXMFooHXAtUpl/t/mCxTRJ+Xggv6L8rnasO9L8X296vXwJgaaDWkIP7GgzqNIVckKwltHz+xzykQ67IDAzboqca4Lb4FvjMjzIu8gmKAIqxbxGxMg0+ZjJsyNiuMZ56xnfuzeUykCw3EUwKomkiMXZoQVn98oTaSrgv0Xui7FmcDBkZv5SEXMv/srbpyw5vnvIzlu8X3EmssQ5s6QAAAAIuh3tJKcjuyw8SvN81ClgZPQCkKexOYhwvM7V8gM+cXAgMNAAECBgcECAkKCwwNDhyHqF7PpyuQ3RAnAAAAAAAAyAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQAJA4CEHgAAAAAAAdTDJe7bGnfT+9m5QI8uSF/7iEuG9njBiva4LtzDm1KwAgkLBwgKBAEDAgA=

(note: I changed some characters as I am not sure whether this is sensitive data)
```

I didn't know this format before, any idea how to extract this kind of transaction data from ready, signed tx in solana web3 js? Also, would appreciate letting me know how it is named and how does it work in general.